# Onclick change text and tel

Tags: javascript, href, tel

Scrip that reveals a phone number on click

```
 <script>
    function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "<?php echo $phone ?>"
    }
    </script>
```

href

```
$STRING .= '<a href="tel:" onclick="changeText(this)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"></a>';
```

when clicked it reveals $phone, but it isn't callable.

how to reveal and call it?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't click the anchor to call the number, because the number is never added to the href, what you want is a href that looks like `href="tel:5647564354"` etc.

```
function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "<?php echo $phone ?>";
    id.href = "tel:<?php echo $phone ?>";
}
```